# What is AWS Wavelength used for?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I found this information online. but I didn't find more. Please, someone, could you tell me when we use the wavelength? Then why?

> AWS Wavelength enables developers to build applications that deliver ultra-low latencies to mobile devices and endusers. Wavelength deploys standard AWS compute and storage services to the edge of telecommunication carriers’ 5G networks. Developers can extend a virtual private cloud (VPC) to one or more Wavelength Zones, and then use AWS resources like Amazon EC2 instances to run applications that require ultra-low latency and a connection to AWS services in the Region.

AWS Wavelength used for?

Comment: Sounds like [CDN](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) for mobile apps

Answer (score 0):

**AWS Wavelength** is just like having an Availability Zone in a phone carrier's 'edge' network.

This is important when latency matters. I live in Australia, and accessing websites in the USA is notably slower than local websites. This is because communications is limited to the speed of light, and the world is quite large!

Similarly, if phone apps need *very* fast communications, the fastest connection to a server would be in the phone carrier's network. That's what AWS Wavelength provides.

What is it used for? Probably not much at the moment, but presumably AWS had enough interest in the service to start deploying it. People laughed when they invented cloud computing, so maybe they're onto something!

Comment: But you could solve your example, accessing US websites while living in Australia, with existing technology in the AWS portfolio and you should solve it for all users in Australia not just for 5G users on a particular big carrier. One thing I noticed while researching this topic and looking for competitors and alternative solutions for this use case was that it is almost always only offered by one provider in the respective country. I'm not saying it's useless, but unless you are bidding on a contract as an architect or solution provider to win a customer you can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

It's another type of network gateway. What it does is already explained in the quoted section: reduce latency for applications that need it.

## What is it?

As I said, it's another kind of specialized network gateway to provide services to users of a particular carrier. How do other carriers reduce latency for their customers? I don't know yet. My best guess is that you would have to make a special agreement with the respective providers, build out or rent infrastructure in special locations and so on. AWS solves it the flexible AWS way. Is it good? Ask the people who have access to business relevant numbers. Take a look at other network gateways and network access options offered by AWS, then look at the problems which 5G and upcoming standards try to solve and either you see value in investing time to learn it or you don't and you can safely ignore it. There seems to be much magical thinking involved here when people try to explain the technology and business value, which is a bad sign for me to continue looking further into such things until better information is available.

You need a apply for access to AWS Wavelength, and you are very likely going to deploy VPCs in in most if not all wavelength zones to service customers with specialized applications which require very low latency in mobile networks. Needless to say that also comes with additional cost. You will know when the time is right to learn more about this product, at least that's what I hope for.